# Porque não consigo fazer a conexão com o PostgreSQL?

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, postgresql

Me interesso muito por programação mas sou novo na área e preciso entregar esse trabalho ao professor. Mas não consigo resolver esse erro.

```
package dal;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class ConectaBd {
    public static Connection conectabd() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{

        try{
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432","postgres","123");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conecxão bem sucedida !");
            return con;
        }

        catch(SQLException error){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Não foi possível conectar !");
            return null;    
        }
    }
}
```

Esse é o erro:

> mai 22, 2017 10:19:47 PM org.postgresql.Driver connect GRAVE: Error in
>   url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432 CONSTRUÇÃO PARADA (tempo total:
>   3 minutos 23 segundos)

Comment: Aparentemente está faltando o nome da database na url da conexão `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/suaDataBase` em `getConnection`

Comment: o user @brow-joe estpa correto, https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/80/connect.html

Answer (score 1):

Está faltando o nome do database.

```
public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException{
        try {
             Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");                             
             return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/mybd?user=eu&password=eu");                         
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());            
            throw new SQLException();            
        }        
    } 
}
```